# Will attacks deflected by Genji hit all enemy players?

Tags: overwatch

When Genji uses the deflect ability, does the deflected attack deal damage to any enemy player in its path or just to the one that fired?

Comment: From [the wiki](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Genji#Deflect): While the ability is active, most frontal ranged attacks will be deflected in the direction of Genji's crosshairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deflected attack will deal damage to everybody that it hits. You can aim the deflected attack to your cross hairs if you want to hit someone else besides the guys who are shooting you.

Comment: [Relevant .gif](http://plays.tv/s/KzxJa7J2--Ny) as proof. Deflect the Hanzo ult, kills Mei and Bastion.

Answer (score 10):

Attacks that are reflected by Genji are fired in the direction that Genji is facing - in other words, where his crosshairs are aiming. That means you still have to aim at your targets if you want to damage them. Simply using Reflect is not enough.

Comment: Christ no wonder I've been utterly failing when trying to kill Bastion's as Genji using reflect